# How to remove duplicate records from NSDictionary based on some key?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

```
submittedTestArray =   [{
        scheduledTestId = "F7F15169-2FB6-4E47-A971-BAAD40D152AB";
        studentId = "8b3df16f-ff2f-4ad4-839c-6a937b79854d";
        submittedTestId = "37F20871-FB3A-47AA-B254-9E5409C5E4C4";
    }, {
        scheduledTestId = "440947DD-0A01-4DB8-8DD5-CCFA8F852FD3";
        studentId = "8b3df16f-ff2f-4ad4-839c-6a937b79854d";
        submittedTestId = "681689DC-B35C-491C-A737-AB19D9116FD9";
    }, {
        scheduledTestId = "440947DD-0A01-4DB8-8DD5-CCFA8F852FD3";
        studentId = "8b3df16f-ff2f-4ad4-839c-6a937b79854d";
        submittedTestId = "681689DC-B35C-491C-A737-AB19D9116FD9";
    }, {
        scheduledTestId = "440947DD-0A01-4DB8-8DD5-CCFA8F852FD3";
        studentId = "e18ead0a-d0fc-4e15-96ee-ecbd32880d97";
        submittedTestId = "A46965C6-14B1-401E-97C5-AD5BADCC02EE";
    }]
```

I want all the NSDictionary objects uniquely based on ***scheduledTestId***

If i will consider above example then it will give me two NSDictionary objects.

Temporarily  i am using following code.

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueKeys =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[submittedTestArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.scheduledTestId"]];
NSMutableArray *submittedTestUniqueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:uniqueKeys.count];
for (SubmittedTest *submittedTest in submittedTestArray) {
    if ([uniqueKeys containsObject:submittedTest.scheduledTestId ]) {
        [uniqueKeys removeObject:submittedTest.scheduledTestId];
        [submittedTestUniqueArray addObject:submittedTest];
    }
}
```

***submittedTestUniqueArray*** is contain my desired output i.e.

```
[{
    scheduledTestId = "F7F15169-2FB6-4E47-A971-BAAD40D152AB";
    studentId = "8b3df16f-ff2f-4ad4-839c-6a937b79854d";
    submittedTestId = "37F20871-FB3A-47AA-B254-9E5409C5E4C4";
}, {
    scheduledTestId = "440947DD-0A01-4DB8-8DD5-CCFA8F852FD3";
    studentId = "8b3df16f-ff2f-4ad4-839c-6a937b79854d";
    submittedTestId = "681689DC-B35C-491C-A737-AB19D9116FD9";
}]
```

Comment: I want all the NSDictionary objects uniquely based on scheduledTestId

Comment: But from your "question" I read, that you have already accomplish it.

Comment: I want better solution for that. I dont want to create new NSMutableArray to accomplish this.

Comment: Why? Is it to slow? Is it to much code? I don't know a better solution.

Comment: Ya, i want better solution that will increase the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of for-in loop, go with a for loop and after iterating each time

```
if ([uniqueKeys containsObject:submittedTest.scheduledTestId ]) {
        [uniqueKeys removeObject:submittedTest.scheduledTestId];

    }
else
{
[submittedTestArray removeObjectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}
```

Comment: Does changing the "for-in" loop to "for" loop really helps? I dont think so! If it really improves the performance then I would like to read the theory behind it

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what I am writing is up-to the mark but still I am daring to answer.

Ideally what you have tried is perfect. Coz to remove duplicate records from the dictionary, there is a need to have a bunch of records, in this case
an array named **uniqueKeys** with **scheduledTestId** values, to compare each dictionary element with all other elements for duplication.

And this is what exactly you have done.

The only improvements I can suggest in this code is instead of `NSMutableArray *uniqueKeys`

change it to `NSArray *uniqueKeys;` and after finishing the comparison & collecting the dictionary objects with the unique records, flush the array elements instead of removing them one by one.

Coz having 2 mutable arrays, one having simply unique keys & other having dictionary objects with unique records doesn't make any sense. Of course I presume that you dont need an array with only unique keys. What you need is dictionary not an array, right?

So in short I dont find any performance improvements in your code.

@ALL: Please let me know if there are any improvements in my technical knowledge.

CHEERS HAPPY CODING